# How do I use a Python library in emacs?

Tags: python, path

I am trying to use [Webkit](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WebKit), but I can't get emacs to find the necessary python library EPC that I installed via pip (in Anaconda). Here is the error message:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "epc")
  require(epc)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/evar/.emacs.d/myPackages/webkit.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2348
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/evar/.emacs.d/myPackages/webkit.el" "/Users/evar/.emacs.d/myPackages/webkit.el" nil t)
  require(webkit)
```

I am using High Sierra.

Comment: The mysterious "High Sierra" appears to be a version of Mac OSX.  For future reference, people who don't use a Mac are unlikely to recognise names like that, so more clarity would be helpful.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use xwidgets-webkit instead.

Answer (score 1):

`require(epc)` in the stack trace indicates that `epc.el` is not found in your Emacs `load-path` variable.

You'll probably want to do something like:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/directory")
```

for the directory where `epc.el` lives.